# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject

Tags: json, spring

I develop rest api by the using Spring.

So My rest api call another api. For example Oracle ORDS.

```
private String processBackground(String object, String url, HttpMethod templete) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        logger.warn(object);
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(object, headers);
        logger.info(request.toString());

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;
        responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, templete, request, String.class);

        logger.info(responseEntity.getBody());
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

this section get error, in my opinion.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-30T09:18:54.586+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONObject",
    "path": "/mainrequest"
}
```

Help me! 
Thanks ;)

Comment: If you know the structure of the received object, you can replace `restTemplate.exchange(url, templete, request, String.class)` by `ResponseEntity<MyObject> destObject=restTemplate.exchange(url, templete, request, MyObject.class)` and then return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message means that you don't have an HttpMessageConverter in your spring context capable of handling JSONObject conversion to String for the MediaType application/json.

Have a look at this post about message converter and how to implement your own : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

Quick fix could be to expect response entity body as JSONObject, as you should have the default JSON HttpMessageConverter, like this :

```
ResponseEntity<JSONObject> responseEntity;
```